# Symfony - Voter - How add new ROLE

Tags: symfony

my user initially doesn't have the ROLE, so Voter doesn't granted access. How can I add a ROLE so that depending on the situation it granted access in Voter??

In Controller I call:
$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted(TestVoter::VIEW, $entity);

In my $entity I have users to release access

In voter I try:

```
> protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject,
> TokenInterface $token) { $user = $token->getUser();
> foreach ($subject->getAccount() as $account) {
>      if (in_array($user->getId(), $conta->getAccount())) {
>          return true;
>      } return false; }  }
```

but it does not access because the user does not have this ROLE. How can resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, when you create a User entity using make command, you will have something like:

```php
public function getRoles(): array
{
    $this->roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

    return array_unique($this->roles);
}
```

It will allow you to have at least ROLE_USER.